# Converting 1080p video to 720p

Tags: video, cmd.exe

How can I convert a 1080p video to a 720p video, preferably without any external software? If so, can this be done in a Command Prompt?

Answer (score 5):

It cannot be done in  Command Prompt as it won't be able to re-encode a video from higher to lower resolution. Use software like Handbrake or Any Video converter to do the same for you.

Also check [this](http://www.movavi.com/video-converter-command-line/how-it-works.html) command line video converter.

Comment: Or how about just using [ffmpeg](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99643/how-can-i-convert-a-1080p-wmv-video-to-a-720p-video)? Works on Windows too.

Comment: According to this it can be done http://superuser.com/questions/714804/converting-video-from-1080p-to-720p-with-smallest-qualiti-loss-using-ffmpeg