# Converting video from 1080p to 720p with smallest quality loss using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, high-definition

I stack with my high quality movie: 1080p with 60fps. The trouble is lags while playing.

I tried to convert it to 720p with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i MyMovie.mkv -r 60 -s hd720 MyMovie_720p.mkv
```

But I there is significant quality loss because bit rate decreased from 32.3 Mbps to 2.8 Mbps.
How can I specify right bit rate for video stream, and left all other stream copied pristine?

Input file mediainfo:

```
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 2h 58mn
Bit rate                                 : 32.3 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.260
Stream size                              : 40.2 GiB (92%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 116 r2019 9cc407d
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:-2:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=10 / psy=1 / psy_rd=0.80:0.20 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=32 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=6 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=0 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=6 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=14.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=50000 / vbv_bufsize=62500 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / pb_ratio=1.30 / aq=1:0.60
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Matrix coefficients 

                 : BT.709-5, BT.1361, IEC 61966-2-4 709, SMPTE RP177
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Here is an example which should give you the highest quality video (I'm not speaking about the resulting file size). Note that this video might not be playable on all devices or players:

```
ffmpeg -i MyMovie.mkv -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:a copy MyMovie_720p.mkv
```

To get a "visually lossless" quality, you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i MyMovie.mkv -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -c:a copy MyMovie_720p.mkv
```

Now let's see what we have here:

The [scale video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) is for resizing the video. You just set one size – which is the height in this example – and use `-1` for the other dimension. ffmpeg will recalculate the correct value automatically while preserving the aspect ratio.

Quality controlled with the `-crf` option:

> The range of the quantizer scale is 0-51: where 0 is lossless, 23 is
>   default, and 51 is worst possible. A lower value is a higher quality
>   and a subjectively sane range is 18-28. Consider 18 to be visually
>   lossless or nearly so: it should look the same or nearly the same as
>   the input but it isn't technically lossless.
>
> The range is exponential, so increasing the CRF value +6 is roughly
>   half the bitrate while -6 is roughly twice the bitrate. General usage
>   is to choose the highest CRF value that still provides an acceptable
>   quality. If the output looks good, then try a higher value and if it
>   looks bad then choose a lower value.

You can find more info in the [x264 encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).

You control the tradeoff between video encoding speed and compression efficiency with the `-preset` options. Those are **ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow**. Default is **medium**. The **veryslow** option offers the best compression efficiency (resulting in a smaller file size for the same quality) but it is very slow – as the name says.

The audio will be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) directly from the input file to the output file without any changes.

Comment: LordNeckbeard - thanks for edit. I didn't have enough time to type all the details

Comment: You example is setting height to 720 not width.

Comment: Can you do this backwards http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20439/mask-720p-as-1080p-video

Comment: To also copy subtitles in mkv without converting, you can add `-scodec copy`.

Comment: I think to get 720p you must set the width to 1280 i.e. not  `-vf scale=-1:720` but `-vf scale=1280:-1`.

Comment: @chovy The question asked for 720p, which means a height of 720. The width can be anything, so leaving it as -1 is best to allow ffmpeg to decide based on the previous dimensions. Only time you'd need to specify the width is if it decides on an odd value for the new width.

Comment: @Wlerin That's wrong. 720p is only 720 tall in 16:9. 720p should always be 1080 wide, and 1080p should always be 1920 wide. The _height_ can be anything, hense @cdlvcdlv is correct. Should be `-vf scale=1280:-1`.

Comment: @MiniGod Strictly speaking neither 1080p nor 720p mean *anything* outside of 16:9. However, the height is literally baked into both designations, while the width isn't. Perhaps more accurately, you should pick whichever of `1280:-1` and `-1:720` makes the result fit between `1280x720`. Neither `1920x720` nor `1280x1200` are 720p.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: `-vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease` to fit the video into 1280x720 ([source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling))

Comment: also try adding `-sws_flags lanczos` which is better than `bicubic` for downscaling ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/582198/how-can-i-get-high-quality-low-size-mp4s-like-the-lol-release-group))

Answer (score 7):

In case you like to scale in a different size, there are some limitations on the FFMPEG scaling dimensions. It does not accept each height, here is a small list of the best recommendations for dimensions.

Video codecs perform better when the width and height in pixels are multiples of 16. While you can use any width and height in your encoding settings, non-optimal dimensions can result in poor image quality and reduced frame rate. For the best image quality and playback, you should use width and height dimensions for your video that are multiples of 16; your next best choice is multiples of 8, and after that, multiples of 4.

```
Recommended width and height for videos with 16:9 aspect ratios:

Best Choice:     2nd Best:        3rd Best:
Multiples of 16  Multiples of 8   Multiples of 4
1920 x 1080      1792 x 1008      1856 x 1044
1280 x 720       1152 x 648       1216 x 684
1024 x 576        896 x 504       1088 x 612
 768 x 432        640 x 360        960 x 540
 512 x 288        384 x 216        832 x 468
 256 x 144        128 x 72         704 x 396
                                   576 x 324
                                   448 x 252
                                   320 x 180
                                   192 x 108
```

Answer (score 1):

downscale to 720p = fit the video into 1280x720

```
ffmpeg \
 -i input.mp4 \
 -vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:force_divisible_by=2 \
 -sws_flags lanczos \
 output.mp4
```

documentation: [ffmpeg scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1)

`-sws_flags lanczos` is better than the default `-sws_flags bicubic` ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/582198/how-can-i-get-high-quality-low-size-mp4s-like-the-lol-release-group))

`force_divisible_by=2` is required for h264:

```
[libx264 @ 0x853040] height not divisible by 2 (1280x533)
```

examples:

```
ratio  1080p      720p

16:9   1920x1080  1280x720
16:10  1728x1080  1152x720
 3:2   1620x1080  1080x720
 4:3   1440x1080   960x720
 5:4   1350x1080   900x720
 1:1   1080x1080   720x720

 2:1   1920x960   1280x640
24:10  1920x800   1280x534
```