# FFMPEG: x265 video encode options

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, x265

There's quite a bit of info about using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) ([more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)) to encode with **x265: HEVC**. However, when I try to encode my video from [x264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264) to [x265](http://x265.org/) with scaling to reduce overall bit rate in order to save even more space on my hard drive, I am still missing the `Frame Rate Mode` option. Currently, my video after encoding has changed to [CFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video#Constant_bit_rate_versus_variable_bit_rate) whereas it was originally [VFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_frame_rate). The command is

`ffmpeg -i input -vsync 2 -vf scale=1280:-1 -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset:v slow -crf 24 -rc vbr_hq -qscale:a 1`

The output is OK, but I'm curious about the frame rate mode. Do you have any idea to output VBR with x265?

I am also curious about the information in this file, for I can understand some of the details, but not others.

Files info from `MediaInfo` [x264](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jnpExlc6G0QY-fmemrhMM5NUFluKVcyl/view?usp=sharing) and [x265](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Ry43ONbihaU_rn59hrOuhjxjLfpde_P/view?usp=sharing).

Some other information [Rate-control](https://slhck.info/video/2017/03/01/rate-control.html), [x265](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/introduction.html), [Encode H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)
[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/714804/converting-video-from-1080p-to-720p-with-smallest-qualiti-loss-using-ffmpeg)
[Super User encode x264](https://superuser.com/questions/908295/ffmpeg-libx264-how-to-specify-a-variable-frame-rate-but-with-a-maximum)

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -i in -vf vfrdet -an -f null -` on both files. I suspect a handful of frames had their duration regularized.

Comment: Hi @Gyan,  I am not sure understand well what you mean. So I call the command as you suggest 
%ffmpeg% -i %input720% -vf vfrdet -an -f null -  and here is the result [x264 output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kdVzJeYvc75gC9Hj_B3OniEf1PXwFjRM) , [x265_720output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LHI26GA1KHMc0RJDlh_Ir9cLQPigZidv)

Comment: I'll post an answer in a while - this has nothing to do with the encoder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input is `23.976` fps, exactly represented as `24000/1001`. So each frame ideally should be `1001/24000` seconds long. But the input has a [timescale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337235/5726027) of 90k (90000), and in that timescale the ideal duration requires `3753.75` ticks, which isn't possible, as timestamps are integers. So, what your input does is assign half the frames `3753` and the other half `3754`. This makes it "VFR". The output has a timescale of 24000 in which the ideal duration can be exactly represented by 1001 ticks.